# How can i remove image from preview as well as file tag Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to remove a particular image from preview panel as well as file tag while there is multiple images selected.

I will add HTML sections to show preview of the selected images.

1. I am selecting multiple images (2, 3, 4 images)

[image]

When user removes a selected images using "Remove" option from preview panel, I am trying to remove the preview and it's selection from file tag.

[image]

**Example:**
Already 2 files chosen and removed one file but file tag selection shows still 2 files.

[image]

I have done this code for add image preview and delete preview.

```
      <div class="form-group">
           <lable>Select Multiple Image</lable>
           <input type="file" name="image[0][]" class="form-control filesimage0" multiple onchange="selectpreview(0,event)">
      </div>
  </div>

function selectpreview(id,e)
{
    var files = e.target.files,
        filesLength = files.length;
      for (var i = 0; i < filesLength; i++) {
        var f = files[i]
        var fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onload = (function(e) {
          var file = e.target;
          $("<span class=\"pip\">" +
            "<img class=\"imageThumb\" src=\"" + e.target.result + "\" title=\"" + file.name + "\"/>" +
            "<br/><span class=\"remove"+id+"\" id=\"image_" + id + "\">Remove</span>" +
            "</span>").insertAfter("#showimage"+id);

            $(".remove"+id).click(function(e){
             $(this).parent(".pip").remove();

          });

        });
        fileReader.readAsDataURL(f);
      }
}
```

Comment: What have you done so far? show your existing code

Comment: `reset` the `form` and `replace`  the `img src`

Comment: Hello, @DevsiOdedra can you please give me an example code.?

Answer (score 0):

You can unlink the index of `files` array and rearrange the array.
Let's say you have 4 files [1, 2, 3, 4] with their indices as `id` value of the preview element so that on clicking the `remove` button you can map the `id` with its respective index in the `files` array and splice the array accordingly.

```
const files = e.target.files; // 4 files
files.splice(YOUR_ID_VALUE, 1); // you want to remove 3rd file then YOUR_ID_VALUE is 2
```